# How to partition by groups of N in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, grouping

I have the following data frame:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [
    ( 1, "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "desktop"),
    ( 2, "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "desktop"),
    ( 3, "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "mobile"),
    ( 4, "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "desktop"),
    ( 5, "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "mobile"),
    ( 6, "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "desktop"),
    ( 7, "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "desktop"),
    ( 8, "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "desktop"),
    ( 9, "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "desktop"),
    (10, "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "mobile"),
    (11, "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "desktop"),
    (12, "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH", "desktop"),
    (13, "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH", "mobile"),
    (14, "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH", "desktop"),
    (15, "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH", "mobile"),
    (16, "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH", "desktop"),
    (17, "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH", "desktop"),
    (18, "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH", "desktop"),
    (19, "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL", "desktop"),
    (20, "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL", "mobile"),
    (21, "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL", "desktop"),
    (22, "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL", "desktop"),
    (23, "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL", "mobile"),
    (24, "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL", "desktop"),
    (25, "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL", "desktop"),
    (26, "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL", "desktop"),
    (27, "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL", "desktop"),
    (28, "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL", "desktop"),
    (29, "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL", "desktop"),
    (30, "III", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL", "mobile")
]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("id", IntegerType(),True),
    StructField("text", StringType(),True),
    StructField("title", StringType(),True),
    StructField("target_url", StringType(), True),
    StructField("display_domain", StringType(), True),
    StructField("device", StringType(), True)
])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)

columns = [
    "text",
    "title",
    "target_url",
    "display_domain"
]

windowSpecByPartition = (
    Window.partitionBy(
       columns 
    ).orderBy("id")
)

overall_row_number_df = df.withColumn(
    "overall_row_number",
    F.row_number().over(windowSpecByPartition)
)
```

I want to partition into groups of 5 per group even if the group is incomplete.

What I am expecting to have is the next table:

| id | text | title | target_url | display_domain | device | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 1 |
| 2 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 1 |
| 3 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | mobile | 1 |
| 4 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 1 |
| 5 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | mobile | 1 |
| 6 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 2 |
| 7 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 2 |
| 8 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 2 |
| 9 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 2 |
| 10 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | mobile | 2 |
| 11 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 3 |
| 12 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | desktop | 4 |
| 13 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | mobile | 4 |
| 14 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | desktop | 4 |
| 15 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | mobile | 4 |
| 16 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | desktop | 4 |
| 17 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | desktop | 5 |
| 18 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | desktop | 5 |
| 19 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 6 |
| 20 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | mobile | 6 |
| 21 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 6 |
| 22 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 6 |
| 23 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | mobile | 6 |
| 24 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 7 |
| 25 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 7 |
| 26 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 7 |
| 27 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 7 |
| 28 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 7 |
| 29 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 8 |
| 30 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | mobile | 8 |

In the end, I need to end up with 8 groups of data, this is really similar to the behavior of the [in_groups_of](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) of Rails.

Comment: What are the criteria used for partition (what columns)?

Comment: @HoangMinhQuangFX15045 Is there is the columns variable: text, title, target_url, display_domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide `row_number` by 5 then round up to get a unique id for each group within a partition then partition by `columns` and the additional id:

```
(
overall_row_number_df.withColumn("sub_group", F.ceil((F.col("overall_row_number") / 5)))
    .groupBy(columns + ["sub_group"]).agg(F.collect_list("device").alias("devices"))
).show(truncate=False)
```

gives you:

| text | title | target_url | display_domain | sub_group | devices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | 1 | [desktop, desktop, mobile, desktop, mobile] |
| AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | 2 | [desktop, desktop, desktop, desktop, mobile] |
| AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | 3 | [desktop] |
| EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | 1 | [desktop, mobile, desktop, mobile, desktop] |
| EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | 2 | [desktop, desktop] |
| III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | 1 | [desktop, mobile, desktop, desktop, mobile] |
| III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | 2 | [desktop, desktop, desktop, desktop, desktop] |
| III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | 3 | [desktop, mobile] |

Answer (score -1):

After creating the overall_row_number_df DataFrame, you can create the following two DataFrames using the provided logic to achieve the desired result.

1. DataFrame temp_df with flag column: This DataFrame will have a new column named flag, which assigns a value of '1' to every 6th record and '0' to the remaining records.
2. DataFrame final_df1 with group_id: This DataFrame aggregates the flag values and generates a group_id based on the sum of the flag column.

```py
    temp_df = overall_row_number_df.withColumn("flag",when((overall_row_number_df.overall_row_number%5).cast('int')=='1',lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)))
    
    windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(lit('1')).orderBy("id").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
    
    final_df = temp_df.withColumn("group_id",F.sum("flag").over(windowSpec)).drop("flag").drop("overall_row_number")
    
    final_df.show(100,truncate=False)
```

Here is the Result :

| id | text | title | target_url | display_domain | device | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 1 |
| 2 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 1 |
| 3 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | mobile | 1 |
| 4 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 1 |
| 5 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | mobile | 1 |
| 6 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 2 |
| 7 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 2 |
| 8 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 2 |
| 9 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 2 |
| 10 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | mobile | 2 |
| 11 | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | desktop | 3 |
| 12 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | desktop | 4 |
| 13 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | mobile | 4 |
| 14 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | desktop | 4 |
| 15 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | mobile | 4 |
| 16 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | desktop | 4 |
| 17 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | desktop | 5 |
| 18 | EEE | FFF | GGG | HHH | desktop | 5 |
| 19 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 6 |
| 20 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | mobile | 6 |
| 21 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 6 |
| 22 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 6 |
| 23 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | mobile | 6 |
| 24 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 7 |
| 25 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 7 |
| 26 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 7 |
| 27 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 7 |
| 28 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 7 |
| 29 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | desktop | 8 |
| 30 | III | JJJ | KKK | LLL | mobile | 8 |

Comment: This is very inefficient as `partitionBy("1")` will cause all of the data to be sent to the same partition, it's the same as not partitioning at all

Comment: But isn't it giving expected output? Do you suggest any efficient solution to achieve the result ?

Comment: At the cost of the job being extremely inefficient to the point of  probably not being able to run on most spark use cases as this requires the whole dataframe to fit in a single partition on a single node. `group_id` doens't have to be exactly like described in the question in order to be able to partition the dataframe like described

Comment: @Sergio Flores ,Can you please verify if this solution has resolved your issue?